# File.txt converted into a string

Tags: python, string, file-conversion

I am trying to figure out how to convert a file.txt into a string so I can use the find() operation to find certain text in a .txt file. Does anyone know how to convert a .txt file into a string using python 3?

**First Time Asking A Question On Stack Overflow**

-Sorry if it’s bad

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Tried anything? What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as thefile:
    string = thefile.read()
```

You can refer to the [Python docs on File I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) or other tutorials as well for more info on this.